# Angular searchbar error: Argument of type 'unknown' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to create this angular app that fetchs data from an API. Everything is more or less working but now it's the time to implement a search function and I'm having trouble in my component.ts.

This is my whole service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, take } from 'rxjs';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class MoviesService {

  baseUrl: string;
  apiKey: string;
  language: string;
  region: string;

  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient
  ) { 
    this.baseUrl = 'https://api.themoviedb.org/3/';
    this.apiKey = 'dd4d819639705d332d531217b4f7c6b6';
    this.language = 'en-US';
    this.region = 'US';

  }
  
  getCatalog() {
    return this.http.get(`${this.baseUrl}movie/top_rated?api_key=${this.apiKey}&page=1&language=${this.language}&region=${this.region}`) as Observable<Catalog>;

 }

 getMovie(id:string) {
  return this.http.get(`${this.baseUrl}movie/${id}?api_key=${this.apiKey}&language=${this.language}&region=${this.region}`) as Observable<Movie>;

}

getSearchedMovie(username:string): Observable<any> {
  return this.http.get(`${this.baseUrl}search/movie?api_key=${this.apiKey}&language=${this.language}&region=${this.region}`) as Observable<Movie>;

}}

export interface Catalog {
  page: number;
  results: Movie[];
  total_pages: number;
  total_results: number;
}
export interface Movie {
  title: string;
  id: number;
  overview: string;
  original_title: string;
  poster_path: string;
}
```

And this is my component.ts:

```
import { NgFor } from '@angular/common';
import { Component, NgModule, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { debounceTime, distinctUntilChanged, switchMap, take } from 'rxjs';
import { Catalog, Movie, MoviesService } from 'src/app/services/movies.service';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { FormControl, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-catalog',
  templateUrl: './catalog.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./catalog.component.css']
})
export class CatalogComponent {

  searchForm:FormGroup = new FormGroup({
    search: new FormControl('')

  })


  catalog: Movie[];
  constructor(
    private moviesService: MoviesService,
    public movieList:Array<any>=[],
  ) { 
  
    
    this.searchForm.get('search')?.valueChanges.pipe(debounceTime(1000)),
    switchMap((v) => this.moviesService.getMovie(v)).subscribe((v) => {
      this.movieList=v?.users
    })

  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.moviesService.getCatalog().pipe(take(1)).subscribe(res =>{
      this.catalog = res.results;
      console.log("this catalog dentro del observable", this.catalog);
    });
  }
};
```

This line is what gives me problems:

```
this.searchForm.get('search')?.valueChanges.pipe(debounceTime(1000)),
    switchMap((v) => this.moviesService.getMovie(v)).subscribe((v) => {
      this.movieList=v?.users
    })
```

The errors are for the second (v) and the .subscribe:

1. Argument of type 'unknown' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
2. Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type 'OperatorFunction<unknown, Movie>'.

Do you see something that I might be missing?

Comment: Have you written the code inside the constructor? Because I do not see any method getting invoked on search.

Comment: Not sure if this is related to your problem, but I think you have an extra parenthesis after `debounceTime(1000)` that should be at the end of your entire statement.

Answer (score 0):

The operator `SwitchMap` must be put inside the `pipe` stack tree.

```
this.searchForm.get('search')?.valueChanges.pipe(
      debounceTime(1000),
      switchMap(v =>  this.moviesService.getMovie(v)
    )).subscribe(v => {
      this.movieList=v?.users
    })
```